# How to break words in a responsive table cell?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following table that contains 3 columns. On a mobile view, I successfully wrapped the email but the cell, where this email is contained, still has the with of a none wrapped email as you can see on the print screen below.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <td id="email-td" class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="mailto:shakira.wisoky@example.com">shakira.wisoky@example.com</a>                
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-5">
            Blanditiis id dolores maxime blanditiis. Aut sunt quia cupiditate reprehenderit et.
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#email-td {
    /*max-width: */
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxm0dq7h/1/).

[image]

How can make this email table fit in a 12 columns view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use bootstrap columns for a table.  "col-xs-6" works best for divs.  I would recreate your html using the div tag rather than a table, if you want it to be responsive.  Tables were never really made to be responsive and are annoyingly difficult to manually fix their unresponsiveness.